# Selenium Webdriver, click a button with class

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

In Java, how do I click a button with class, without ID, XPath or Class name?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'click a button with class, without... Class name?'

Answer (score 2):

You can click by the `compose` text with `xpath`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'COMPOSE')]")).click();
```

Or with `cssSelector`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div:contains('COMPOSE')")).click();
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector div:contains('COMPOSE') is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
Command duration or timeout: 11.21 seconds

Comment: @Ram4Automation I fixed it in the answer, forgot the `//`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this instruction

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='button']")).click();
```

Comment: It's not work out:(, I need to click a compose button in GMAIL after logged in.

Comment: can you extract the html code of the button so we can define a working selector

Comment: <div gh="cm" style="-moz-user-select: none;" class="T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3" role="button" tabindex="0">COMPOSE</div>

Comment: maybe you could try driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[role='button']")).click();

Comment: Yes it's clicking, but not a compose button, its clicking the search button

Comment: try to select the compose value driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[role='button'][value='COMPOSE']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

As an XPath:

```
//div[@class='T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement composeBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", composeBtn);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.